# multiple commands inside a awk

Tags: awk

sry opening a new thread but awk is driving me nuts! ><  im trying to run a few command assignments inside a single awk  but i cant get it to work  please help if this is ez for u :P  i can't get the syntax to work

edit: im using /bin/bash

```
for f in `seq $nlinpE $loopE`; 
do 

awk  -F ","'  
BEGIN {}    
'$f'  { dataI2[$f]=$2;
    dataI3[$f]=$3;
    dataI4[$f]=$4;
    noD1[$f]=$dataI1[$f];
    noD2[$f]=$dataI2[$f];
    noD3[$f]=$dataI3[$f];
    noD1i[$f]=`echo "$nlinpN1 + $dataI1"|bc -l`;
    noD2i[$f]=`echo "$nlinpN1 + $dataI2"|bc -l`;
    noD3i[$f]=`echo "$nlinpN1 + $dataI3"|bc -l`;
    }   
'${noD1i[$f]}' { 
    dataIi2[$f]=$2;
    dataIi3[$f]=$3;
    dataIi4[$f]=$4;
    }

'${noD2i[$f]}'  { 
    dataIii2[$f]=$2;
    dataIii3[$f]=$3;
    dataIii4[$f]=$4;
    }

'${noD2i[$f]}'  { 
    dataIiii2[$f]=$2;
    dataIiii3[$f]=$3;
    dataIiii4[$f]=$4;
    }
END{}                 
' <aoa_5.inp;
```

done

input is like:

```
 17,   3.22854114,  0.562598288,  0.384291202
 18,   2.96085286,  0.085116826,  0.285071939
 19,   3.40070796,   2.27838659,  0.302027524
 20,   3.20035744,  0.333615214,  0.262585849
 21,   2.85644341,  0.258691043,  0.369726121
 22,   3.73537922,    1.3267405,  0.295917094
 23,   3.69372559,   1.32601321,  0.306054831
 24,   3.28857207,   0.63199228,  0.378117412
 25,   3.27523994,  0.695856452,  0.377585977
```

imjust assigning variables atm, getting the number w/o commas
i get this syntax type of error:

```
awk: 9: unexpected character '`'
awk: 10: unexpected character '`'
awk: 11: unexpected character '`'
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
(standard_in) 2: syntax error
awk: line 1: syntax error at or near {
^C
```

thx

Comment: Tyically you only need one BEGIN and END block in 1 awk program. The normal processing is to operate on each line of text. Code inside `{ ...}` blocks that are not BEGIN/END blocks would qualify as normal processing. BEGIN and END mean 'do this before/after normal processing'. You have multiple blocks of all types in your code. Best to show input and desired output. Good luck.

Comment: check new format please help :)

Comment: Still need sample output!! Also, why are you using external variables `'${noD1i[$f]}'`, etc? If you must use external vars, we need some bash code outside of awk that sets values for the variables. Good luck.

Comment: Can you please explain clearly what do you mean by this - `imjust assigning variables atm, getting the number w/o commas`. May be if we have a clear problem description, we can offer some assistance. If you just need numbers and no commas then thats a pretty bad way of doing it. :P

Comment: you wrote 'boils down to those 3 add lines with echo""' . why are you using `bc` to perform math functions, awk can do any math function you can think of right inside. Also, I'm seeing now that `'${noD1i[$f]}'` is assigned inside awk. Just refer to it as noD1[f] . It seems like you're making this way too hard for yourself. Good luck.

Comment: first of all thx for all the comments,  all variables are being assigned inside awk. All i wanna do atm is to read this file, get those numbers, only numbers to do some math with them l8r. i'm only reading the file and throwing all the contents in 9 arrays.Thing is.. this awk is inside a for loop with "f'. at each value of f i have data from 3 different lines whose numbers i get from operating the line at f. with this line i get the other 3 ${noD1i[$f]}, ${noD2i[$f]}, ${noD3i[$f]} (i didnt know this syntax noD3i[f] works :)) any better?  thx again

Comment: expected output??? Also, so above comments about $f indicates there is another set of input you're trying to process besides the data included, yes? Also (as you seem to know) `${noD1i[$f]}` is bash syntax, and to be useful inside of awk, the value of the var must be turned into a reg exper or string to be useful. try `/${noD1i[$f]}/` . Good luck.

Comment: Done with edits on comments ;-)

Comment: i was elaborating a large awnser but i dont have rep to answer yet >< so atm i cant post the output properly w/o confusing everybody  thx for the reply.. i might drop this script for a while..im only trying to speed my original script cuz its taking over 1 day to read this input file and record all the variables into arryas.. i got 8 awk commands atm, thing is these awk comands are loping nearly 100k times... if i had got this format working it would go down to 2...  meh :( thx for the patience

Comment: unless you have the answer to your problem, you shouldn't post it as an answer. All I mean is one line of sample output, right? You can bet that a  big part of your processing time is the `...| bc -l` 3x for each line. Tbat math can be done internally to awk. You need to step back, take the time to read thru the excellent awk tutorial at http://grymoire.com AND then revise your question WITH small samples of inputs and expected outputs. If you have multiple steps, then make separate questions for each step. Clarify!!! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: thing is..i thought i'd be able to handle and nearly master bash as ez as matlab kinda of sintax which is more like perl in like 5 days, and i am not working all the 12 working hours of the days on it lol.. yeah ambicious...i underestimated the syntax lol...but thanks for the feedback.. guess ill have to sit for a while.. i am overloaded in fact these days.. again.. ty :P

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this will help you clean up your syntax a little so we can understand what you're trying to do.

BEGIN and END blocks are optional. Ignoring patterns for the moment, an awk program might look like this.

```
BEGIN {
    # Things to be done before you start processing rows.
}
{
    # Things to be done for each row.
}
END {
    # Things to be done after processing the last row.
}
```

If you don't happen to need BEGIN or END blocks, it might look more like this.

```
{
    # Things to be done for each row.
}
```

This awk program assigns the value of $2, $3, and $4 to the variable dataI, and prints it once for each row.

```
{
  dataI = sprintf("%s %s %s", $2, $3, $4);
  print dataI;
}
```

That assignment has no effect on the values of $2, $3, and $4.

Comment: the whole thing boils down to those 3 add lines with `echo""` and the assignment of variables.. gotta get this syntax to work :(

Comment: can i add inside awk? .. either with bc or exp? can i perform any command inside awk? cuz i've only seen prints anywhere i go on the web

Comment: awk is a programming language. [Here's a tutorial.](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) You can do arithmetic in awk; you don't need to run bc for that.

Comment: ty! i've been through this website.. but the time i spent on it was unable to find an answer; i should dig deeper when i got more time :P