# Using a variable defined inside AWK

Tags: awk

I got this piece of script working. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302642/multiple-commands-inside-a-awk) is what i wanted:

input

```
3.76023 0.783649 0.307724 8766.26   
3.76022 0.764265 0.307646 8777.46   
3.7602 0.733251 0.30752 8821.29   
3.76021 0.752635 0.307598 8783.33   
3.76023 0.79528 0.307771 8729.82   
3.76024 0.814664 0.307849 8650.2   
3.76026 0.845679 0.307978 8802.97   
3.76025 0.826293 0.307897 8690.43
```

with script

```
!/bin/bash 

awk -F ', ' ' 
{

    for (i=3; i<=10; i++) {
        if (i==NR) {
        npc1[i]=sprintf("%s", $1);
        npc2[i]=sprintf("%s", $2);
        npc3[i]=sprintf("%s", $3);
        npRs[i]=sprintf("%s", $4);
        print npc1[i],npc2[i],\
        npc3[i], npc4[i];
        }
    }
} ' p_walls.raw 

echo "${npc1[100]}"
```

But now I can't use those arrays `npc1[i]`, outside awk. That last echo prints nothing. Isnt it possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

- AWK is a separate process, after it finishes all internal data is gone. This is true for all external processes/commands. Bash only sees what bash builtins touch.
- `i` is never 100, so why do you want to access `npc1[100]`?
- What are you really trying to do? If you rewrite the question we might be able to help...

Comment: ops, just added some input there... yeah the input is over 1k lines, so 100 should be fine.. i kinda heard sth about losing the variables after exiting awk..  question is: is there no way to save those values w/o writing another file? i wanted to store those input values in arrays to operate with them l8r in the code.. and ill have to store values from 2 different files :(

Comment: you can process the output of `awk`. but I still don't know what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: what i want is simple: i got 2 large files. i want to store all the interesting data in the memory but using arrays to operate on these data down in the code. i,e., i wanna loop the contents of one file over each line of the other.. and it takes lots of time if i call awk at each loop pass. Hence, i wanted to load both files in memory and work with them. thats why i wanted to use the var from inside awks. i know i can operate inside awk but i got these 2 loops using 2 files..so at some point ill have to use the values defined inside awk outside (store in memory, hopefully)

Comment: I guessed all of that... I still don't know .. ahm.. nevermind :/ Do the whole thing either in awk or in bash.

Comment: Sorry, but all of @yi_H 's answer and comments are correct. But there's really no problem loading 2 sets of data into 2 separate arrays in awk. `awk '{if (FILENAME == "file1") arr1[i++]=$0 ; #same for file2; } ; END {for (i=1;i<f1max;i++) {arr1[i] ....; for j=1;j<f2max;j++) arr2[j] ...}' file1 file2` You'll have to fill in a few blanks here on vars needed and their values. OR get an awk book for the weekend and be up and running by Monday. It's easy. You can probably figure it out from http://grymoire.com/Unix/awk.html Good luck!

Comment: I thought this sounded familiar. I we've talked before. Arg! and you still haven't shown sample out output! update your quest. pls! If you want to have dialog with people that leave comments, be sure to include their id, like @ bakabrr or @ shellter ,. typically as the first word and with a trailing space and ':' char.  (The stupid input box validation will only allow 1 @ name example. see last one below for correct format). Note you get a popup picker after you type the '@' sign. For people with spaces in their name, you just remove the spaces in the name, like New User=@NewUser. Good  luck.

Comment: yo @shellter !!! hi dude.. i got to read the manual, thats when i figured out how to do what i wanted to do..and with ur last comment above i reduced my initial crappy code with 10e^10 calls of awk to a single 1! i'll basically do just one awk call now ! :P horay!! gonna be happy on monday :P  (ps i did got the popup picker for name but not sure if it worked ><)

Comment: plus i know output is important, but idk if u understood, but my question had always been about  translating the data from a specific row/column from a file to arrays.. so input=output but stored at arrays.. anyway u did gave me the cherry of my cake with that 2 file comment.. thx a lot :p

Answer (score 1):

(Cherry on the cake is always good!)

Sorry, but all of @yi_H 's answer and comments above are correct.

But there's really no problem loading 2 sets of data into 2 separate arrays in awk, ie.

```
awk '{
  if (FILENAME == "file1") arr1[i++]=$0 ; 
  #same for file2; } 
 END {
      f1max=++i; f2max=++j;
      for (i=1;i<f1max;i++) {
        arr1[i] 
        # put what you need here for arr1 processing 
        #
        # dont forget that you can do things like
        if (arr1[i] in arr2) { print arr1[i]"=arr2[arr1["i"]=" arr2[arr1[i]] }
      }
      for j=1;j<f2max;j++) {
        arr2[j] 
        # and here for arr2
      }
 }' file1 file2
```

You'll have to fill the actual processing for arr1[i] and arr2[j].

Also, get an awk book for the weekend and be up and running by Monday. It's easy. You can probably figure it out from grymoire.com/Unix/awk.html

I hope this helps.